# 1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null"

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-views

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','placeholder': 'Enter Username'}))
    password= forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Password'}))
    email=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Email'}))
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password','email']


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fullname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter fullname'}))
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=['fullname']
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            variable=form.save(commit=False)
            variable.password = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(request.POST['password'],rounds=12000,salt_size=32)
            variable.save()
            profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.username=variable.username
            profile.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'account created for { username }')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    context={'form':form , 'profile_form':profile_form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html',context)
```

I have created two table auth_user (default) and users_profile.When i register the User default data goes into auth table but fullname is not inserted into user_profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not link the `profile.user` to a `User` object. You can do this with:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            variable=form.save(commit=False)
            variable.set_password(variable.password)
            variable.save()
            profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = variable
            profile.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'account created for { username }')
            return redirect('login')
    # …
```

In order to set the password, you probably better use Django's [**`.set_password(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password).

Comment: Thanks!
however I am unable to login now(it saysusername and password incorrect.) I am useind default login django

Comment: @RamPatil: likely you should not encrpyt the password yourself. You can use the `.set_password` method.

Comment: (1062, "Duplicate entry '3' for key 2")
fullname is not inserted in other db